# Do While and While loop exit unexpectedly?

Tags: c, centos, do-while

I was writing the following C code on Centos 6.5 using gcc-4.7 but program does not waiting for Type Y/N: statement it immediately exits after result.Either of the codes are not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    char ch='y';

   do
    {
            printf("Enter Number 1:\n");
            scanf("%d",&a);
            printf("Enter Number 2:\n");
            scanf("%d",&b);
            printf("Result is:%d\n",a+b);
            printf("Type y/N:\n");
            scanf("%c",&ch);
    }while(ch=='y' || ch=='Y');
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

OR

```
    #include<stdio.h>

   int main()
    {
      int a,b;
      char ch='y';

       while(ch=='y' || ch=='Y')
       {
            printf("Enter Number 1:\n");
            scanf("%d",&a);
            printf("Enter Number 2:\n");
            scanf("%d",&b);
            printf("Result is:%d\n",a+b);
            printf("Type y/N:\n");
            scanf("%c",&ch);

       }
         return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to read the documentation of every used function, notably [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). You should test the result of `scanf`. You should compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`) (when coding with pointers, you'll want also to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is: `%c` won't skip leading whitespace, so if there's a newline in the input stream (i.e. from your previous `scanf` entry i.e. number 2 say in your case) then `scanf` call will consume it immediately.

One way to solve the issue is to put a blank space before the specifier in the format string:

```
scanf(" %c", &c);
```

The blank in the format string tells `scanf` to skip leading whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

When you execute:

```
scanf ("%d", &b);
```

and enter, for example, `42<enter>`, the `42` is read and the `<enter>` is left in the input buffer.

Then it's picked up by the `scanf("%c",&ch);` which is one of the format strings that *doesn't* skip whitespace before attempting to read. From `C99 7.19.6.2 /8`, though largely unchanged in C11:

> Input white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a [, c, or n specifier.

Many input specifiers tend to skip white space *before* they start reading the real data, `c` is one of the exceptions.

For simple code like this, you could *possibly* get away with using a space in the format string since (from that same section `/5`):

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read.

So, you would use something like:

```
scanf (" %c", &ch);
```

Though that's *not* going to help if you enter a number like `47b` for example :-)

At some point, every C developer realises the inadequacies of the standard input mechanisms, and [writes their own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921).